# React ES 6 Classes refs

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am very new in react native and I tried to refactor a source code from old react into react using ES 6 Class, but I got an error 'Cannot read property 'close' of undefined'. Can anyone help me why this.refs.drawer in closeDrawer is undefined?

```
closeDrawer = () => {
   applicationActions.setDrawerStatus(false);
   this.refs.drawer.close();
}

openDrawer = () => {
   applicationActions.setDrawerStatus(true);
   this.refs.drawer.open()
}

setDrawerState(value) {
   this.setState({ isDrawerOpened: value });
}

render() {
   return (
     <Drawer ref="drawer"
       type="static"
       openDrawerOffset={DRAWER_OFFSET}
       panOpenMask={.5}
       onOpen={() => this.setDrawerState(true).bind(this)}
       onClose={() => this.setDrawerState(false).bind(this)}
       content={<DrawerScene closeDrawer={this.closeDrawer().bind(this)} />}  >

       <MainView
          drawerStatus={this.isDrawerOpened}
          closeDrawer={this.closeDrawer().bind(this)}
          openDrawer={this.openDrawer().bind(this)}
       />
     </Drawer>
  );
}
```

Regards

Comment: What do you see if you `console.log(this.refs)`?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** I did not notice that you were using arrow functions in your component's member functions, so you do not need to `bind` them. There were some other issues, though

This is a binding issue. This should work:

```
closeDrawer = () => {
   applicationActions.setDrawerStatus(false);
   this.refs.drawer.close();
}

openDrawer = () => {
   applicationActions.setDrawerStatus(true);
   this.refs.drawer.open()
}

setDrawerState(value) {
   this.setState({ isDrawerOpened: value });
}

render() {
   return (
     <Drawer ref="drawer"
       type="static"
       openDrawerOffset={DRAWER_OFFSET}
       panOpenMask={.5}
       onOpen={() => this.setDrawerState(true)}
       onClose={() => this.setDrawerState(false)}
       content={<DrawerScene closeDrawer={this.closeDrawer} />}  >

       <MainView
          drawerStatus={this.isDrawerOpened}
          closeDrawer={this.closeDrawer}
          openDrawer={this.openDrawer}
       />
     </Drawer>
  );
}
```

The problem with your code is that you are applying bind to the result of a function call. For instance, when you do `this.setDrawerState(true).bind(this)`, the function is called, returns the appropriate value, and then `bind` is applied to it. This usually would result in an error, but here you are also trying to access a `ref` that has not yet been set up (because before that happens all `prop` values have to be evaluated before passed to the new component, which is exactly the problem here, the function is called before the component is instantiated).

Just so you know a bit more about `bind`: it is a property of a function object, so you need to access it from the reference to that function (in this case, its name). The result of `bind` is a new function with the same behaviour of the original one, save for the new `this` value or any other parameters you pass.

Comment: You should also not use a string as for you're ref, change it to `ref={drawer => this.drawer = drawer}`

Answer (score 0):

Try to set ref like this instead of a string:

```
drawer = null;
closeDrawer = () => {
   applicationActions.setDrawerStatus(false);
   this.drawer.close();
}

openDrawer = () => {
   applicationActions.setDrawerStatus(true);
   this.drawer.open()
}

setDrawerState(value) {
   this.setState({ isDrawerOpened: value });
}

render() {
   return (
     <Drawer ref={((component)=> this.drawer=component)}
       type="static"
       openDrawerOffset={DRAWER_OFFSET}
       panOpenMask={.5}
       onOpen={() => this.setDrawerState(true).bind(this)}
       onClose={() => this.setDrawerState(false).bind(this)}
       content={<DrawerScene closeDrawer={this.closeDrawer().bind(this)} />}  >

       <MainView
          drawerStatus={this.isDrawerOpened}
          closeDrawer={this.closeDrawer().bind(this)}
          openDrawer={this.openDrawer().bind(this)}
       />
     </Drawer>
  );
}
```

Comment: The result will be the same, since the error is not on the ref prop, but on the event handling props.